# SwiftUI Skeleton animation bouncing when it should only be fading in and out

Tags: swiftui

Animation should just fade in and out until content loaded, but it bounces up and down while fading in and out.

```
struct FadingSkeletonView: View {
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = true
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .opacity(isAnimating ? 0.3 : 1.0)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.2).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: isAnimating)
        
            .onAppear {
                self.isAnimating = false
            }
    }
}
```

This is the group bouncing

```
Group {
    FadingSkeletonView()
        .frame(height: 250)
        .padding()
    
    FadingSkeletonView()
        .frame(height: 40)
        .padding([.leading, .trailing])
}
```

If i remove the Spacer() then it reduces the vertical animation movement.

```
var body: some View {
VStack { 
  Group {
    FadingSkeletonView()
        .frame(height: 250)
        .padding()
    
    FadingSkeletonView()
        .frame(height: 40)
        .padding([.leading, .trailing])
  }
 }Spacer() // Removing this reduces the up and down animation
}
```

Here is the full Code including the FadingSkeletonView and the content which is hidden until it has been loaded. The Animation should loop (fading in and out) until the content load is complete.

It seems as though removing the Spacer() and .padding() at the bottom of the code reduce the amount of bouncing by the animation. I believe it's redrawing the view each time the animation loops but can't seem to isolate the FadingSkeleton rectangles.

```
import SwiftUI

// Define a SwiftUI View named FadingSkeletonView
struct FadingSkeletonView: View {
    @State private var isAnimating: Bool = true  // Controls the animation
    
    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
            .foregroundColor(.gray)
            .cornerRadius(10)
            .opacity(isAnimating ? 0.3 : 1.0)
            .animation(.easeInOut(duration: 0.5).repeatForever(autoreverses: true), value: isAnimating)
            .onAppear {
                isAnimating = false
            }
    }
}


struct ProjectDashboardView: View {
    let project: Project?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            if let unwrappedProject = project {
                
                // Check if imageUrl is available
                if let url = unwrappedProject.imageUrl  {
                    // Use AsyncImage for iOS 15+ to handle image loading
                    AsyncImage(url: url) { image in
                        image.resizable()
                    } placeholder: {
                        ProgressView()
                    }
                    .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fill)
                    .frame(height: 250)
                    .cornerRadius(10)
                    .clipped()
                    .padding()
                } else {
                    // Placeholder in case imageUrl is not available
                    Rectangle()
                        .foregroundColor(.gray)
                        .frame(height: 250)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .padding()
                }
                
                Text(unwrappedProject.title)
                    .font(.largeTitle)
                    .fontWeight(.bold)
                
            } else {
                
                FadingSkeletonView()
                    .frame(height: 250)
                    .padding()
                
                FadingSkeletonView()
                    .frame(height: 40)
                    .padding([.leading, .trailing])
            }
            
        }
        Spacer()
        
            .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not seeing any bouncing when running on an iPhone 14 simulator with iOS 17. What environment are you using?

Comment: Testing on iPhone 12 device, iOS17

Updated the question with more info about the content which is bouncing.

Comment: Still not seeing it even on iPhone 12 simulator and iOS 17, sorry. But how are you expecting the two views inside the ```Group``` to be laid out? Try using either an ```HStack``` (for horizontal layout) or a ```VStack``` (for vertical layout) instead.

Comment: It seems to be interacting strangely with my Spacer() in the View body.